# Equivalence for componentDidMount in Hook clear my logs array

Tags: react-hooks

I'm coding with Hooks from React 16.14.

I try to have a single connection with a socket at the first acces of the function (like componentDidMount with component) but when I do it, my function did not run correctly : my logs array is always with the last element.

Here is my testing coding.

```js
export default function ShowLog(props) {
    const [logs, setLogs] = useState([]);

    const traitementDataMQTT = async data => {
        console.log("Start Reception => " + DateUtilities.toISODate(data.DateHeure) + " - data.Message");
        console.log(logs)

        let _logs = [...logs];

        console.log(_logs)

        _logs.unshift(DateUtilities.toISODate(data.DateHeure) + " - Nouveau message");

        console.log(_logs)

        setLogs(_logs);

        console.log(logs)
        console.log("End reception")
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("Connect socket");

        let socket = io.connect(process.env.REACT_APP_IP_SOCKET, { secure: true });

        socket.on("/NiCo/IHM/Message", data => traitementDataMQTT(data));

        return () => { console.log("Close socket"); socket.close(); }
    }
//Here is the difference
    ) // In this case I deconnect and reconnect at each modification (like componentDidMount + componentWillUpdate)
    //or
    //, []) // In this case, I connect to the socket once (like componentDidMount only) but my logs is always have only one element in the array (or not when start)

//Code for checking
    useEffect(() => { console.log("Log changed"); console.log(logs); }, [logs]);
    useEffect(() => { console.log("All change"); console.log(logs); });

    console.log("Test - Function");
//---------

    return (
        <div>
            <table>
                <tbody id="Logs">
                    {
                        logs.map(
                            (item, index) =>
                                <tr key={index}>
                                    <td>
                                        <p>{item}</p>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>)
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    );
}
```

You can see the both result on console
[image]

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Any help for this situation please?
Even else, I will come back to the component with componentDidMount and componentWillUpdate.